# In Google App Engine (Python), how do you boost the resources of your application server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This used to be done in the adminstrator console. Now, according to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Configuration), it's controlled by a setting in the application's configuration files.

I updated my `app.yaml` file to include these lines and redeployed it:

```
#
# Module Settings
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Configuration
#
module: default
instance_class: F2
```

However, I haven't noticed any improvement in my application's performance. Specifically, I have a (cpu-bound) script that was taking 4-5 secs to run and there has been no difference since the change.

So my question is: am I doing this correctly? And is there a way to confirm (for example, in the logs or elsewhere in the admin console) the level at which my application's servers are running?

I should note that I am testing this on an unbilled application. Although I couldn't find any information in the docs that indicated this feature was limited to billed applications, I know that some features are unavailable on unbilled apps.

Comment: F2 means increased processor and memory. Are you sure your script is bound by either of those factors, rather than (as is likely) I/O?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Good question. I should have mentioned that. I'm pretty sure the script is processor-bound. It is calculation-heavy and runs much faster on my local development machine. Neverthless, even if it was the case that I/O was the issue, my question would still stand.

Comment: See the instance chart. The number of billed instances will be 2xnumber of active instances. Because appengine bill is based on F1 instance

Comment: @marcadian Is this the [instance chart](http://i.imgur.com/TGuv2jW.png) you're referring to? This screenshot was taken just after running my script. I don't see anything there that indicates that I'm running an F2 instance.

Comment: @klenwell: yup, but usually I look at the old console. If it's using F2, the billed should be roughly 2x the number of active instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings you have there look correct.

If you are using modules, and it looks like you are, you can confirm the frontend instance class is what you set it to by viewing the "Versions" page on the old app engine console at http://appengine.google.com/

If you aren't using modules you can view the instance type on the "Application Settings" page.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to check the frontend instance class using the new cloud console.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize the old console was still available. I see under Application Settings that my application is still set to F1. Any idea why my settings in `app.yaml` didn't take?

Comment: I figured out answer to question in previous comment. I updated Ian's answer to include information.

Comment: My [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6922917) was rejected (even though I feel it provides information needed to fully answer the original question). @ian-lewis, perhaps you can include it yourself?

Comment: Are you using the preview app engine commands from the Google Cloud Platform SDK? For some reason if you use "gcloud preview app deploy" the module settings don't take (it actually spits out a warning about it). Use the Google App Engine SDK instead.

Comment: The edit was rejected by stackoverflow editors for good reasons. It was suggested to put the info in a comment so I'll write it here: 

Before you can set the module performance settings using your `app.yaml` file, it appears that you have to migrate your application's Performance Settings for Modules on the Application Settings page in the [App Engine console](http://appengine.google.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you look under Instances in the application dashboard you can see which ones you currently have running.

Comment: I tried that. I don't see any indication of the instance class on that screen. Here's a screenshot of what I see: http://imgur.com/awYjqLk